# SassError: failed to @extend class: tailwind vue can't unite several tailwind classes into a single custom class

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, tailwind-css

I have a `vue` component that looks like this:

```
<template>
    <ul class="list-reset flex justify-between flex-1 md:flex-none items-center">
        <li class="flex-1 md:flex-none md:mr-3
                    sm:text-xs md:text-xs lg:text-xs xl:text-sm">
            <a class="inline-block py-2 px-4
                    text-white no-underline" href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>

        <li class="flex-1 md:flex-none md:mr-3
                    sm:text-xs md:text-xs lg:text-xs xl:text-sm">
            <a class="inline-block py-2 px-4
                    text-white no-underline" href="#">Link2</a>
        </li>

       ...

  </ul>
</template>
```

As can be seen, all navbar links have the same tailwind classes. I want to unite all those classes into a single class `navbar-item`. I tried to add the following to the `.vue` file:

```
<style lang = "scss" scoped>
    @import "../assets/css/tailwind.css";
    @import "../assets/css/style.css";

    .navbar-item {
        @extend .flex-1, .md\:flex-none, .md\:mr-3,
            .sm\:text-xs, .md\:text-xs, .lg\:text-xs, .xl\:text-sm;
     }
</style>
```

However I get the

```
SassError: ".navbar-item" failed to @extend ".flex-1".
```

error.

I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use **@apply** to inline any existing utility classes into your own custom CSS. Check [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives/#apply)

e.g.

```
/* Won't work: */
.btn {
  @apply block bg-red-500;
  @apply hover:bg-blue-500;
  @apply md:inline-block;
}

/* Do this instead: */
.btn {
  @apply block bg-red-500;
}
.btn:hover {
  @apply bg-blue-500;
}
@screen md {
  .btn {
    @apply inline-block;
  }
}
```